# The graphics card on my old MacBook Pro broke. How do I transfer my files if I cannot see anything?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, graphics

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro and the graphics card broke leaving me unable to see anything. Everything else still works. I hadn’t backed anything up because I’m an idiot and now I don’t know how or if it’s possible to transfer my files over to the new MacBook. Any help is greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Have you tried connecting it to an external monitor?  If it works, it means that your graphics card is broken but at least you'll be able to have a screen to see what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Doug, I did and unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to boot the old mac into Target Disk Mode, which turns the whole thing into an external drive for the new Mac.

Connect the two together using a Thunderbolt 3 cable (it may need to be a "Thunderbolt 3 cable", rather than just a USB C one).

Then boot the old Mac while holding down T.

You can then run Migration Assistant, which will copy everything over for you.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac

Without wishing to be too schoolmastery, once you've retrieved all your files, I hope this will encourage you to backup your files in future!

Comment: Just writing the same...

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will give it a go as soon as I get the cable. I will definitely be backing up my files from now on!!

Comment: Simplest solution and best advice !

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an external monitor. The screen on my 2015 MacBook Pro stopped working and I've been using the laptop exclusively via an external Apple Cinema Display for nearly 2 years. In my case, the computer still thinks the original display is working so I do things like use the mirroring option in System Preferences when items are off-screen.

The only problem I've had during that time occurred during a particularly troublesome restore from a bootable backup disk. But, after several discussions with support from the ones who make my backup software (Carbon Copy Cloner) I was able to get that working.

Even if you don't own an external monitor, you might try borrowing one to see if this works.

Comment: But your *graphics card* still functions - is that correct?

Comment: I don't know that much about hardware. When the laptop is open I just see a black screen filled with fine horizontal lines. If I move my mouse in that screen I can see a vertical line where the mouse is. Now I just keep it closed after starting and everything functions perfectly using my external monitor. It's as if converted to a desktop.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for your help! Connecting to a monitor was the first thing I did to see if it was just the screen or an internal issue. Unfortunately it did not work. From my understanding the graphics card has burnt out, meaning I get a blank screen no matter what I do. It sounds like a common issue with the 2017 model due to overheating issues.

Comment: Ok, I learned something here. Also, I regularly provide (very carefully) external ice packs during intense operations to avoid overworking the laptop fan since heat problems are a top source of computer failure.